# CustomUser Migration Failed Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-custom-user

I tried making my migrations but can these error messages:

```
ERRORS:
accounts.CustomUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'accounts.CustomUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'accounts.CustomUser.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.
accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions' or 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'accounts.CustomUser.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'accounts.CustomUser.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions'.
```

Here is my CustomUserManager:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password, **extra_fields)
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Let me know by making a comment if i should also upload my model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following to **settings.py**:
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'YourAppName.YourClassName'`

Comment: I thought It was there. Thanks for reminding men